# How to append previous line to next line in a file if first character of a line is |

Tags: linux, awk, sed

Input :

```
MAKTG|MAKTX|MANDT|MATNR|SPRAS
ARALDITE AV 5308
|araldite AV 5308
|910|132252374801|E
HARDER HV 5309
|harder HV 5309
|910|132252374901|E
BAYFLEX 5965 I|Bayflex 5965 I|910|132252380101|E
KUPFERPULVER FEIN 2703|kupferpulver fein 2703|910|132252382701|E
```

Needed Output:

```
MAKTG|MAKTX|MANDT|MATNR|SPRAS
ARALDITE AV 5308|araldite AV 5308|910|132252374801|E
HARDER HV 5309|harder HV 5309|910|132252374901|E
BAYFLEX 5965 I|Bayflex 5965 I|910|132252380101|E
KUPFERPULVER FEIN 2703|kupferpulver fein 2703|910|132252382701|E
```

Answer (score 0):

As, according to the chosen tag, you are on linux, you can do it more simple than the answers given in the duplicated question, using  the `-z` option of GNU `sed`:

```
sed -z 's/\n|/|/g'
```

`-z` to process the whole file at once, then replace (`s`) all (`g`) newlines followed by a bar (`\n|`) with a bar only.